# How to create collapsible rows or lists, with prioritized cells showing when collapsed?

Tags: excel, vba

[Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBk1O.png)  I need to create Excel-files for schedules that would contain the activity of the person involved during certain times.

I would like for a schedule in the format of:

```
Person 1     07:00    10:00     Activity 1    [Qualifications of said person]
Person 1     10:00    12:00     Activity 2    [Qualifications of said person]
Person 1     12:00    13:00     Break         [Qualifications of said person]
Person 1     13:00    15:00     Activity 3    [Qualifications of said person]
Person 1     15:00    17:00     Activity 4    [Qualifications of said person]
```

to show the following when collapsed:

```
Person 1     07:00    17:00     Activity 1    [Qualifications of said person]
```

So that most of the cells would actually show the same as the first row, but that the finishing time (17:00) would somehow take priority over 10:00.

I haven't found a way to do this with the collapsible row feature, which doesn't work as it results in only the first row being shown. Is it perhaps something I'll have to accomplish with VBA?

I've attached a template explaining what I want to happen.

The lower "Department A" is the raw data that our management system gives us, now i want to just be able to copy and paste that below our departments, either as a whole or person by person. And then have it be easily collapsible to the upper "Department A" for better visibility and then expandable to the lower one when you feel you need more information. I want to be able to do this for each person, so for example only for person 1, or for two or more.

Comment: Please, define what you understand by "collapsed rows"? Do you want them becoming hidden, do you want deleting them? Something else? Even if you will accept one of the above propositions (or something else) would it be correct to say that "Activity 1" had such duration?

Comment: Yes, it would be correct to say that Activity 1 had such a duration as it would be an overarching activity. What i mean by collapsible is, in short, a list of some sort. I want it to hide the rows in between, and i want them to be expandable again.

Answer (score 0):

Please, test the next code. It should be very fast, using arrays, extract unique persons (using a Dictionary), the first range of the group, the last one and its last End time, then process the obtained Dictionary/arrays:

```
Sub groupPersons()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrInt, i As Long, j As Long
  Dim rngIns As Range, k As Long, dict As Object
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row 'last row on column A:A
  
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  arr = sh.Range("A1:C" & lastR).Value2  'place the range in an array for faster iteration/processing
  For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
        If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
            dict.Add arr(i, 1), Array(i, i, arr(i, 3)) 'load the dictionary key and an array of first row, first row and first End date
        Else
            arrInt = dict(arr(i, 1))                    'load the array with the dictionary item
            arrInt(1) = i: arrInt(2) = arr(i, 3)  'load the current row number and current End time

            dict(arr(i, 1)) = arrInt                    'place back the processed array
        End If
  Next i
  'Create a Union range of the rows to be inserted:
  For i = 0 To dict.count - 1
        addToRange rngIns, sh.Range("A" & dict.Items()(i)(0))
  Next i
  
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
   rngIns.EntireRow.insert xlShiftDown ' insert row above each group
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  
  arr = sh.Range("A1:E" & lastR + dict.count).Value2 'place the range having inserted rows in an array
  Dim ar: ar = arr 'create a clone of arr array
  For i = 2 To UBound(arr) 'place the next row content in the empty row
        If arr(i, 1) = "" Then
            ar(i, 1) = arr(i + 1, 1): ar(i, 2) = arr(i + 1, 2)
            ar(i, 3) = dict(ar(i, 1))(2): ar(i, 4) = arr(i + 1, 4)
            ar(i, 5) = arr(i + 1, 5)
        End If
  Next i
  
  'place the processed array (with an extra row as the first of each person group):
  sh.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(ar), 5).Value2 = ar
  
  'Group the necessary rows (down the newly inserted rows):
  For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
     If arr(i, 1) = "" Then
        Intersect(Range("A:E"), sh.rows(i)).Font.Bold = True
        sh.rows(i + 1 & ":" & i + (dict(ar(i, 1))(1) - dict(ar(i, 1))(0) + 1)).group
      End If
  Next i
  
End Sub

Sub addToRange(rngU As Range, rng As Range)
    If rngU Is Nothing Then
        Set rngU = rng
    Else
        Set rngU = Union(rngU, rng)
    End If
End Sub
```

I did not comment the code, because I need now to leave my office. If it works as you need and want understanding it better, I will also comment it after being at home (after some hours)

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Comment: I'm sorry, my knowledge on VBA is not at all in the range where i would understand how to utilize this. The most I've done previously is make a "Clear" button and an "Add" button.

I'll try to specify further what i am looking for. 

I want a template where i can have different departments as headers of each space. Within those spaces i want there to be cell spaces where i can paste in data for schedules in the expanded format, from which i want to be able to easily collapse and expand this data, with everything showing the first row except the ending time.

Comment: I am driving... Just copy the code in a standard module and run it.

Comment: @Clas Hagström Do you have AnyDesk installed? If so, if you allow a connection, I will show you how to use the above code.

Comment: I do not have AnyDesk, I've tried to run the code but seem to be getting Runtime error 91 so i wonder if maybe some variable hasn't been set? Does it work properly on your end?

I saw now that it is this line
    rngIns.EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown
that the error refers to

Comment: @Clas Hagström Please, install AnyDesk. It is free and it takes less than a minute to install it.  It is difficult to understand what's happening in your environment. I tested the code on my laptop and it works as it should. Did you refresh the page (this one) and use the updated code? The one containing comments, too...

Comment: I'll try, but I can't install that on my work computer so I can't do it today. Have you seen that i edited the main post and also included a picture and an additional explanation of where the data comes from and how it looks? It also explains that the function has to be able to handle multiple people and multiple departments in the same work sheet. 

I've now been able to run the code, and it doesn't seem to work as i would like it to, but we can handle that over AnyDesk, I just wanted you to see the further specification I've provided first.

Comment: @Clas Hagström You wanted to include a picture, but you did not succeeded... I used the visible link address and could see that your question does not match the picture at all. I am afraid that I started thinking I am wasting my time, no offence... If you are not able to explain in words what you try accomplishing, at least **place two pictures**! One showing the existing situation and **a second one showing what you want accomplishing**. I answered your question based on the text data you initially show. Now, I have no idea about what you try doing. I edited your question and placed the link.